# Adding sub documents to an array from within the same document

Tags: mongodb

I have multiple documents in the same collection. Here are the first two documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b21ba6770fbe3753ddfb6f"),
    "activeDateTime" : "11/5/2001",
    "enabled" : 0,
    "regionDescRefId" : ObjectId("5591bdbc807504cd138c9f38"),
    "patientType" : [ 
        ObjectId("5500744ee4b09a58a08b72b5")
    ],
    "allergenWells" : [ 
        {
            "allergenRefId" : 9,
            "column" : 1,
            "row" : 1
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b21ba6770fbe3753ddfb70"),
    "activeDateTime" : "11/5/2001",
    "enabled" : 0,
    "regionDescRefId" : ObjectId("5591bdbc807504cd138c9f38"),
    "patientType" : [ 
        ObjectId("5500744ee4b09a58a08b72b5")
    ],
    "allergenWells" : [ 
        {
            "allergenRefId" : 11,
            "column" : 2,
            "row" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get the allergenWells array and field values from document #2 and place them into document #1 so that it looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57b21ba6770fbe3753ddfb6f"),
        "activeDateTime" : "11/5/2001",
        "enabled" : 0,
        "regionDescRefId" : ObjectId("5591bdbc807504cd138c9f38"),
        "patientType" : [ 
            ObjectId("5500744ee4b09a58a08b72b5")
        ],
        "allergenWells" : [ 
            {
                "allergenRefId" : 9,
                "column" : 1,
                "row" : 1
            },
            {
                "allergenRefId" : 11,
                "column" : 2,
                "row" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

So eventually the allergenWells array will grow.  Any ideas?  I'm kind of new to MongoDB so any assistance that can be provided would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What happens to document #2? Do you want to update the collection after this operation or you just need to return a document with the above result?

Comment: document #2 will go away as will any other documents that get added (document #3, document #4, etc.)  So there will be more than one document within the same collection that I want to add the allergenWells fields and values to the allergenWells array of the document #1.  I am also using v2.6

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways you can go about this. The first one would be via the aggregation framework way. This is when you want a result from aggregating the documents and not updating the collection.

In that case, you'd want to run an aggregation operation that comprises of an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** pipeline to flatten the allergenWells array for aggregating later on using the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline. This allows you to group the documents by the distinct keys and create a merged array using the **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet)** operator.

Consider the following example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$allergenWells" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "activeDateTime": "$activeDateTime",
                "enabled": "$enabled",
                "regionDescRefId": "$regionDescRefId",
                "patientType": "$patientType"
            },
            "id": { "$min": "$_id" },
            "allergenWells": { "$addToSet": "$allergenWells" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "activeDateTime": "$_id.activeDateTime",
            "enabled": "$_id.enabled",
            "regionDescRefId": "$_id.regionDescRefId",
            "patientType": "$_id.patientType",
            "allergenWells": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b21ba6770fbe3753ddfb6f"),
    "allergenWells" : [ 
        {
            "allergenRefId" : 11,
            "column" : 2,
            "row" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "allergenRefId" : 9,
            "column" : 1,
            "row" : 1
        }
    ],
    "activeDateTime" : "11/5/2001",
    "enabled" : 0,
    "regionDescRefId" : ObjectId("5591bdbc807504cd138c9f38"),
    "patientType" : [ 
        ObjectId("5500744ee4b09a58a08b72b5")
    ]
}
```

However, there are some limitations with the above approach especially when you're planning on having the allergenWells array growing, and eventually a result with  document exceeding 16MB in size, or using excessive system memory. 
It may be more scalable to do the in-memory merging of the arrays in your client rather than the database server.

---

The other approach would be ideal when you want to update the collection by merging the two documents and removing the other. This cannot be done atomically as you'd need to loop though a result from the above, 
query the document first, figure out what you want to **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** and then update the document using the values from the aggregation as a matching filter to make sure you don't get concurrent updates in between and remove the other documents with a remove command.

The following example shows this concept:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$allergenWells" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "activeDateTime": "$activeDateTime",
                "enabled": "$enabled",
                "regionDescRefId": "$regionDescRefId",
                "patientType": "$patientType"
            },
            "id": { "$min": "$_id" },
            "allergenWells": { "$addToSet": "$allergenWells" },
            "duplicates": { "$addToSet": "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "allergenWells": 1,
            "dupes": { "$setDifference": ["$duplicates", ["$id"]] }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "allergenWells": doc.allergenWells } }
    ); // update allergenWells array
    db.collection.remove({ "_id": { "$in": doc.dupes } }) // delete other docs
})
```

Comment: Hey chridam. Thanks for your response. The second approach is what I was looking for.  Just enough of a "push" that I needed to solve the problem.  You are awesome!

Comment: @SamTheMan No worries, glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) of mongodb

In your case it will look like this.

```
db.collection.update({
  patientType: <mypatientId>
}, {
  $push: {
    allergenWells: {
      $each: {
        "allergenRefId" : 11,
        "column" : 2,
        "row" : 1
      }
    }
  }
});
```